# Blazor - change text inside input

Tags: input, blazor

I am building the number input component in blazor an i just can't figure it out how to prevent the input to change on mousewheeel up/down. I have parameter 'DisableMouseWheel' in if true i want to prevent the number input for going up or down if mouse wheel is turned. If 'DisableMouseWheel' is true and the mouse wheel is turned it does skip the StepUp/StepDown methods but still change the value. Is there any options to solve this without javascript

I use also the 'Disabled' and 'Readonly' parameters for the input

My code

```
<input type="number"
           step="1"
           disabled="@Disabled"
           readonly="@Readonly"
           @onmousewheel="@OnMouseWheel"
           @onwheel="@OnMouseWheel"
           @bind-value="@_value" />
```

```
protected async Task OnMouseWheel(WheelEventArgs args)
    {
        if (DisableMouseWheel == false)
        {
            if (args.ShiftKey || Disabled || Readonly)
                return;
            if (args.DeltaY > 0)
            {
                await StepUp();
            }
            else
            {
                await StepDown();
            }
        } else
        {
            args.DeltaY = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question: Are you trying to stop the up/down actions (mouse wheel or the up/down arrows in the input) triggering a value update on every change?  You want the behaviour to be the same as entering numbers through the keyboard where the value only gets updated when the input loses focus.

Comment: I wonder why there is a "Post your Answer" option on stackoverflow ... 

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@oninput` event of the checkbox. I implemented your code with that, and it works correctly.

```
<input type="checkbox" @oninput="ChangeMouseWheel"/>prevent the input to change on mouse wheel
<br/>
<input type="number"
       step="1"
       disabled="@Disabled"
       readonly="@Readonly"
       @onmousewheel="@OnMouseWheel"
       @onwheel="@OnMouseWheel"
       @bind-value="@_value"/>
```

@code section:

```
@code
{
bool DisableMouseWheel,Disabled,Readonly;
    int _value=0;

    protected async Task ChangeMouseWheel(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        DisableMouseWheel = (bool)e.Value;
        //StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async Task OnMouseWheel(WheelEventArgs args)
    {
        if (DisableMouseWheel == false)
        {
            if (args.ShiftKey || Disabled || Readonly)
                return;
            if (args.DeltaY > 0)
            {
                await StepDown();
            }
            else
            {
                await StepUp();
            }
        } else
        {
            args.DeltaY = 0;
        }
    }

    protected async Task StepUp()
    {
        _value++;
    }
    protected async Task StepDown()
    {
        _value--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:

In this case i need to disable the @onkeydown:preventDefault and then handle everything in onkeydown event

Comment: Elaborate on what you did to fix the issue as this answer is unclear to others. Give a short example code to show what you did.